# Mips - Taking int User input and using that as a character limit for String

Tags: mips

I want to know how to take the int value a user would enter as use that value as the character limit for a string which the user also has to enter.

ex. 
Enter int = 4 
Enter string = cat

Normally, you would use .space but that's for a set character limit. I already know how to ask the user for the int and string value and how to print it but I don't know how to take their int value and use it as the character limit

Comment: Use system call 9 if you want to allocate a buffer dynamically, and use system call 12 to read characters one by one instead of a whole string at once.

Comment: I'm a beginner at this and so don't really know where I would put that in my code.